# Generic approach and recommendation how to remove dependency

Tags: go, interface

I have a question regarding dependency injection. 
Please consider the example below.

For example, selector() is a function that select something and guarantee return an interface

In this example

bar.node.go

```
type NodeTemplate struct {
     Name string
}

// satisfy interface declared in db.foo.go 
//but never imports anything from db.foo.go
func (node *NodeTemplate) GetUuidName() string {
   if node != nil {
      return node.Name
   }
   return 
}
```

db.foo.go

```
// interface declared in db.foo.go

type Node interface {
   GetUuidName() string
}
```

Option A
// So selector receives a map of Some interface and populate a map

```
func SelectSomething(nodemap map[string]Node, selectFactor string) {
     // selection from db and result populate in a map
}
```

Option B

Another pattern SelectSomething return a Node
and it Interface

So another package will depend on importing Node 
and that will introduce a dependency.

```
func SelectSomething(seleconsomething) []*Node {
  // do selection and return a slice of SomeInterface

n := &Node{} // here it need to be concret type T
return Node
}
```

So based on logic I've described I see the first approach is better but in that approach,  select need do concrete type allocation in order to populate a map.

Consider another example

```
db.foo.go

type Node interface {
   GetUuidName() string
}

func inserter(node *Node) error {
   // do some work 
   node.GetUuidName()
}
```

For a case like in inserter case, inserter has no external dependency, inserter just needs to receive something that satisfies the interface.  Declare interfaces locally and that brake a dependancy.

But in the case of selector example, it has to do memory allocation in order to return or populate a map or return something that has concrete type T. So in both case, it has to have internal re-presentation.

So here is my question can selector somehow at run time figure out a type it receives based on the interface and instantiate an object of that type and insert to a map as an interface or return a slice of the interface. ?

By doing so selector function will have no dependancy on what it receives it just guarantee it will instantiate the same object type T
and return interface.

or can selector return interface but I guess I have to have a bi-directional interface between db package and package X or dynamic dispatcher need to do some magic ?

Comment: I am not a fan of reinventing the wheel, and when it comes to dependency injection (a concept which in the long run imho causes more pain than it does good), [Go has actually a plethora of options](https://rationaleemotions.com/Dependency_Injection_in_GoLang/).

Comment: The [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) is a staple of Java programs that try to do this sort of thing (have a second interface that can create objects of the first-interface type, and pass a factory as a parameter to `SelectSomething()` that needs to create new objects) but it's not especially common in Go that I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

You want a type to behave in a certain way. That is achieved via an interface. This case is no different. Simply add the desired behavior to your interface, as demonstrated below with the `Foo` interface.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Foo interface {
    Bar()
    TypeOf() reflect.Type
}

type Baz struct{}

func (b Baz) Bar() {
    fmt.Println("I am a Fooer!")
}

func (b Baz) TypeOf() reflect.Type {
    return reflect.TypeOf(b)
}

func DoSomeThing(f Foo) {
    f.Bar()
    fmt.Println(f.TypeOf())
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    b := Baz{}
    DoSomeThing(b)
}
```

**<kbd>[Run on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/I0Q8ag04A5X)</kbd>**

Comment: it not exactly what i was asking.   Your example exactly what indicated in the last example.  My question of how foo() in package X can return a slice of *interface or map without actually creating type T inside a package.  so externally receiver can type case to type T2 if type T is a subset of T2.  I guess you can't you need inheritance for that or inside a package you need to create type T itself implement all interface return that as a slice of the interface and on receiver do same so it bi-direction mapping.

Comment: @JohnnyBonelli Yes, for a good reason here is no such thing as inheritance in Go. But you can use composition. I am really not sure I got your question, though. From my point of view, it is overly complicated.